# Is it possible to calculate the optimum load resistor value for a thermistor?

Tags: thermistor

In order to calculate the load resistor for a thermistor, we took the thermistor values over temperature (-40 (1kΩ )--> +86C (320kΩ)) and then tried a variety of load resistor values until the optimum resistance was found that gave the greatest operating voltage range for the thermistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWdSUp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the particular thermistor we looked at, 18.3kΩ gave the greatest voltage range.

Is there a rule of thumb or equation that can be used to quickly home in on the load resistor that gives the best range or perhaps the best linear range for a subset of the full range?

Comment: It would help, if you 1) post datasheets (links) of the thermistors you are interested/comparing, 2) the meaning of "the greatest range", while you specify " (-40 (1kΩ )--> +86C (320kΩ))", 3) how do you load a thermistor (?), any circuity to do that?

Comment: @jay updated to add clarity, i.e. the range of voltages with respect to the source.

Comment: I see. You'd like to get the maximum voltage variation on the thermistor in a resistor-voltage-divider configuration.

Comment: While this is admittedly a frame-change remark, I would never try to use a thermistor to measure a 104 degree C temperature range. Among other things, at higher temperatures the tolerances in real thermistors will eat you alive.

Comment: I found Murata's NTC Thermistor simulator useful. It does generate a fitting equation (to any order): https://murata-chip-ntc-thermistor-output-voltag.software.informer.com/1.9/

Answer (score 4):

The optimum value for range is the square-root mean value or  [the **product mean** of the range endpoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) (with an exponent of 1).

\$\sqrt{1*320}= 17.9\$  [kohm]

The requirement is for the maximal linear range for a PTC with R25, R50 coefficients and a -40 to +86'C operating range.  This means the ratio must linearize the ratio over a 86+40= 126'C range with a midpoint at 126/2=63' midpoint or 86-63=63-40=23'C midpoint.

The "Product Mean" is used for this case to achieve that same ratio from -40 to 23'C as from 23'C to 86'C by mathematical proof (Wiki)

Comment: Woe! Would you please explain it? Is it something like Mean Square Root?

Comment: Agree with Jay, very interesting. Is this your own method or has it been expressed anywhere in a textbook?

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense. :-) "The geometric mean is defined as the nth root of the product of n numbers". Thanks Tony!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bit of a derivation for Tony's answer.

For your voltage divider, the output is the standard
$$\mathcal{H} : \frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}$$

Since you know R2 is bound between a maximum and minimum value, the range of the transfer function is also bound. We can express the range as $$ \Delta \mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}_{max} - \mathcal{H}_{min} = \frac{R_{max}}{R_1 + R_{max}} - \frac{R_{min}}{R_1 + R_{min}}$$
The next step would be to look for a maxima or minima using a derivative.
$$ \frac{d}{dR_1} [\Delta \mathcal{H}] $$

All the algebra will be, as they say, left for the reader. My scribblings found the following:
$$ \Delta \mathcal{H} = A\cdot \Delta R$$
Where dR is the range of R2 (Rmax - Rmin). So the derivative is only concerned with *A*. Further work should find you at
$$ \frac{d}{dR_1}[\Delta \mathcal{H}] = \mathcal{K} \cdot (R_{max} R_{min} - R_1^2) = 0 $$
Where I've collected the denominator items in a catch-all *K* term. Now, we arrive at the result Tony presented, giving us the maximal range for a given value range of thermistor resistance:

$$ R_1 = \sqrt{R_{max}\cdot R_{min}} $$

This derivation is given without warranty. Any faults are my own.

Comment: I was there too. And, up to dH/dR1 is correct.. The rest, I am not convinced, as well as the geographical mean theory. You gotta expand that dH/dR. All that I agreed with Tony is what he meant by the square root coming from. Could you elaborate your thoughts in the posting.

Comment: @jay: Can you be more specific about which part you are not convinced of? I stumbled across this post and am currently also thinking about the reasoning behind that derivation. For my part, I cannot see the reason why we should even look for the maxima/minima of the transfer function... any further hints?